# Compute $\sum\limits_u|u(A)|$ where the sum is over every function $u:A\to B$, with $|A|=n$ and $|B|=r$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> Let's denote $|A|=n, |B|=r$. Calculate the following sum:
>
> $$\sum_{f:A \rightarrow B} |f(A)|$$

As I understand, we must calculate cardinality of images of all different functions.
I was able to make a following observation:

Binomial coefficient to choose different elements $\rightarrow$ cardinality of image

$\binom{r}{1} \rightarrow 1$

$\binom{r}{2}\rightarrow 2^n-2$

$\binom{r}{3}\rightarrow 3^n- \binom{3}{2} (2^n-2)+3$

and so on until we reach $\binom{r}{r}$. Well, this sum would be like this:
$$\binom{r}{1} \cdot 1 + \binom{r}{2} \cdot (2^n-2)+... $$
But it looks pretty complicated to sum up. Any HINTS?

Edit: for $\binom{r}{3}$ it starts to looks like exclusion-inclusion rule, but it is still complicated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Fubini-type approach seems to be in order here... Expanding each $|f(A)|$ as a sum over the elements of $B$ that are in $f(A)$, the sum to be computed is
$$
\sum_{f}|f(A)|=\sum_f\sum_{x\in B}[x\in f(A)]=\sum_{x\in B}\sum_f[x\in f(A)].
$$
How many functions $f:A\to B$ are there, in total? Obviously, $|B|^{|A|}$. How many functions $f:A\to B$ are there, such that $x$ is **not** in $f(A)$? As many as functions $A\to B\setminus\{x\}$, that is, $(|B|-1)^{|A|}$. Thus,
$$
\sum_{f}|f(A)|=\sum_{x\in B}|B|^{|A|}-(|B|-1)^{|A|}=|B|\cdot(|B|^{|A|}-(|B|-1)^{|A|}).
$$

Comment: It is very nice (+1)

Comment: @Ju'x I agree (I can say it, since I certainly did not invent the method...).